# Web API handle 404 if route not match

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, routes

I'm working on Web API 2. For now my route table is

```
public void RegisterRoute(HttpRouteCollection routes) {
    routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

That works fine for urls:

```
http://localhost/api/user
http://localhost/api/user/4
```

When I specify not existing controller name (`http://localhost/api/abcd`) then result is JSON

```
{"message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://loocalhost/api/abc'."}
```

I need to return the same result for urls:

```
http://localhost/api/abc/abc/abc/abc
http://localhost/abc/abc/abc/abc
http://localhost/a
```

Now I have

[image]

How can I return JSON with 404 code for all unmatched routes?

*Note: Some of action like `http://localhost/api/user/4` also can returns 404 with some data in body. So, I need to have possibility handle 404 from action and 404 if route not match.*

Please suggest. I've tried this

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
            <remove statusCode="404" />
            <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/Missing" />
 </httpErrors>
```

But then action that returns 404 also redirects to `/Error/Missing`

Answer (score 0):

U need to set your defaults for this, Currently only ID field is being treated as default not your controller. update your default route like this

```
defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Comment: But I do not have Home controller

Comment: It didn't help :(